Ubuntu 24.04 will not install to Chromebook
I've been working for a while now to get my Samsung Chromebook Pro (Caroline Board) to run Linux by following the docs at mrchromebox.tech and so far I've managed to get the Firmware Utility Script to work properly and flash my firmware to give me a UEFI to boot from. I downloaded Ubuntu 24.04.1 as an ISO and put it on a microSD as a bootable drive by using Rufus and then popped it in and booted it up. Things were just fine until I finished the installation wizard's questions just to have it attempt an installation and fail. Here is a screen capture of the error log it gave me.

I have seen other people trying to fix this same problem and have success with some techniques such as verifying the checksum of the ISO (I did that, it's fine) and creating the boot drive over again in Rufus (I did that, but it didn't help). I have seen people also try to use a different drive, but that is not an option that is available to me. I have also tried running the installer while offline as that has fixed this bug for some people. Nothing has worked! I'm at the end of my rope here. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?
I've now tried to run the installation with WiFi and Bluetooth completely disabled and in airplane mode. I've also tried booting in safe mode, or whatever it's called. Neither of them worked.
